# Character Sort Order SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have a SaaS solution (Software as a Service) database that has a UI pointed to it. When employees leave the company if their account is deactivated in the UI, all their associated work order details are lost. As a workaround, the business would like to add a special character to the beginning of each employee's last name when they leave the company. Ideally, they would like all active employees listed first followed by a list of the former employees identified with a special character. I realize there is danger in not deactivating user accounts. Aside from that, I'm wondering if there are any characters that get sorted after AlphaNumeric values by default when the database collation is set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

The unfortunate part of this issue is that since the database is part of a SaaS solution, we do not have access to alter any code or make any changes to the database or table structures. The only thing we can do is update the values in the last name column.

The issue we're running into is that SQL keeps sorting any name with special characters before names without special characters.

This is the goal:

| LNAME |
| --- |
| LastName1 |
| LastName2 |
| LastName3 |
| *FormerEmployeeLastName1 |
| *FormerEmployeeLastName2 |
| *FormerEmployeeLastName3 |

This is what is happening:

| LNAME |
| --- |
| *FormerEmployeeLastName1 |
| *FormerEmployeeLastName2 |
| *FormerEmployeeLastName3 |
| LastName1 |
| LastName2 |
| LastName3 |

```sql
EXEC sp_helpsort
```

Returns the following details:

```sql
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode Data, 
SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252 for non-Unicode Data
```

I'm using the following code to test different characters using the Dec column via this link https://www.barcodefaq.com/ascii-chart-char-set/ however I have found no characters that SQL will sort like the goal noted above.

```sql
DECLARE @Char INT = 135

SELECT CASE
         WHEN LNAME LIKE '*%' THEN Replace(LNAME, '*', Char(@Char)+' ')
         ELSE LNAME
       END AS LNAME
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT LNAME
        FROM   dbo.Users
       --ORDER BY LNAME 
       ) sub
ORDER  BY LNAME
```

Please let me know if there are any characters that SQL will sort after AlphaNumeric values by default or if there is any workaround or trick to make this happen. The only workaround I can think of is to add 'zzz ' to be beginning of each last name since SQL appears to sort any special characters before AlphaNumeric values.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you have and are willing to share!

Cheers!

Comment: Changing the name to indicate inactive and control sorting is a major kludge at best. I suggest you add an EmployeeStatusCode column to indicate active/inactive (e.g. 'A', 'I'). Then, `ORDER BY EmployeeStatusCode, LNAME`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a SaaS solution and we don't have access to make any changes to the code or database/table structures.